# Understanding Ef Core's ChangeTracker with OwnsOne configuration

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entities, change-tracking, ef-core-5.0

Using EF Core 5 and the ABP framework I have an entity of type `System` which has a owned type `Property`. `Property` itself is not an entity cause it has no identifier, just a value and a default value property:

```
public class System : AuditedEntity<Guid>
{
    public Property<string> Setting { get; set; }
}

public Property<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public T DefaultValue { get; set; }  
}
```

The configuration for the entity looks like this simply:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<System>(b =>
{
    b.OwnsOne(p => p.Setting);
}
```

When I now load a System and update one of the properties of the `Property` object inside and then check the EF Core's changes by looking into the ChangeTracker, I see that EF Core tells me there is something "Added", not "Modified".
The Debug view in ChangeTracker shows this in the LongView:

```
System.Setting#Property<string> (Shared) {SystemId: 92f7a6a3-3453-4fd7-45db-08d972bde903} Added
  SystemId: '92f7a6a3-3453-4fd7-45db-08d972bde903' PK FK
  DefaultValue: ''
  Value: 'new value'
```

Why does it say "Added" and not "Modified"? Because it is not an entity itself? Can I change my configuration to have this visible as a change on the parent (`System` marked as "Modified") since I expect `Value` and `DefaultValue` to be special (=owned) properties of the parent?

The issue is in the end that I cannot handle changes on such owned inner objects the same way like changes on "normal" properties. Is there a best practise for such owned types somewhere?